# How to create admin user in ASP.NET MVC 5 with table aspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to add function in my account controller if user have status 1 then redirect to profile page if user have status 0 then redirect to index page.

I tried with authorize roles but no success user roles utilize two tables and me I want use one table.

If anyone has any idea or has a method like this I want admin user

the code source :

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }`   
      `
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRBKm.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pZva.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeFXt.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Handful of issues here.Spelling and grammar are horrendous, code should be within the question, not in pictures. Help us help you. As written, this question requires way too much effort to understand on our part.

Comment: Yeah, not a well formed question, but assuming ASP Identity with a custom field, you can check it doing something like: `var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == myUserName);` then check your custom status field. Posting code is more helpful that images.

Comment: thankyou very much Steve Greene to check the custom status i  create something like this  if (user.Status == 1){ return redirect("profile") but my questions how do this in account controller

Comment: i put the Code Source in my questions but my problem where i put this function with switch result

Answer (score 0):

You could either reroute in your home page, or do something like this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == model.UserName); // or email
        if (user.Status == 1) return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Account");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");        
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Steve Greene I really want to thank you very lot  I asked this problem to several people but no reponse and anyone help me you are the only  who knows this method and help me to open this solutions thank you again

Comment: No worries. Let me know how far you get. The code above assumes you have a context and Identity is properly configured.